# regex in groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I need to remove "" from the both ends of the line

"/home/srinath/junk/backup"

and to display like this /home/srinath/junk/backup

How can we achieve this in groovy ?

thanks in advance,
sri..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a regex. If you always want to remove the first and last characters you can do this with

```
'"/home/srinath/junk/backup"'[1..-2]
```

Alternatively, to remove all double quotation marks use

```
'"/home/srinath/junk/backup"'.replaceAll'"', ''
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to replace `^"|"$` with the empty string. The `^` and `$` are the beginning and end of string anchors, respectively. `|` is the alternation metacharacter.

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info/Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) and [Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)

---

#### Snippet

These were tested on [`lotrepls.appspot.com`](http://lotrepls.appspot.com/):

```
Groovy >>> println('"hello" "world"'.replaceAll('^"|"$',''));
hello" "world

Groovy >>> println('bleh'.replaceAll('^"|"$', ''));
bleh

Groovy >>> println(''.replaceAll('^"|"$', ''));
(blank)
```

As specified, `replaceAll('^"|"$','')` removes *only* doublequotes at the beginning and end of the string, *if* they're there. Internal doublequotes, if there are any, will be left untouched.